# Returning JSX from function yields nothing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, jsx

Followup from [Return JSX from function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47658250/return-jsx-from-function)

I have a a component that needs to check for multiple options and return based on those options. Therefore I have created an outside function that is called in my component return statement to determine the format that will be returned:

```js
render() {
    const { policy } = this.props;
    let deployment = policy.Deployment;
    let value = policy.value;
    let policyLegend = deployment.policyLegend;
    let policyObj = this.valueToPolicy(policyLegend, value);
    console.log(policyObj);
    if(policy.name == "SP4") {
      policyLegend[1].values = this.formatSp4Firmware(policyLegend[1]);
      return (
        <div>
          <Form onSubmit={ (event) => this.handleSubmit(event, this.props) }>
            {
              policyLegend.map((policy) => {
                return (
                  <div key={ policy.id }>
                    <h3>{ policy.displayName }</h3>
                    { this.renderSp4Policies(policy) }
                  </div>
                );
              })
            }
            <Button name={ 'Submit' } type='submit'>Submit</Button>
            <Button onClick={ this.props.onCancel }>Cancel</Button>
          </Form>
        </div>
      )
    } 
  }
```

```js
renderSp4Policies(policy) {
    if(policy.displayName == "Firmware Options") {
      let firmwareDropdownNames = this.formatFirmawareDropdownNames(policy);
      let toggles = policy.values[0][Object.keys(policy.values[0])];
      let toggleOptions = []
      Object.keys(toggles).map(toggle => {
       if(typeof(toggles[toggle]) == "boolean"){
          var obj = {};
          obj[toggle] = toggles[toggle];
        toggleOptions.push(obj);
        }
      })
      return (
        toggleOptions.map(toggleOption => {
          let toggleName = Object.keys(toggleOption).toString();
          return (
            <Form.Field key={ toggleName }>
              <label>{ toggleName }</label>
              <Checkbox toggle />
            </Form.Field>
          )
        })
      )
    } else {
        return (
          policy.values.map(value => {
            return(
              <Form.Field key={ value.name }>
                <label>{ value.displayName || value.name }</label>
                <Checkbox toggle />
              </Form.Field>
            )
          }
        )
      )
    }
  }
```

I have applied some of the answers given from the previous post with moderate success.

Within `renderSp4Policies` what is being returned in the `else` statement displays, however the original `if(policy.displayName == "Firmware Options")` returns nothing.

Appreciate all advice, thank you in advance!

Comment: what do you get when you log `toggleOptions`?

Comment: I get two outputs in the console actually, one with the correct array of objects `0 : {IPv6 for PXE Boot: true}
1
:
{Front Camera: true}
2
:
{Rear Camera: true}
3
:
{USB Port 1: true}
4
:
{Devices: true}
5
:
`
and another log with just an empty array..

Comment: these are not valid keys for an object. they got spaces, if you have spaces in your key you should wrap the key with `" "`. are you sure you don't get any errors?

Comment: It's just how Stack is formatting the results when I paste them in, it's a valid array of objects. And yeah no errors